# Phrase for arranging a meeting - 'anytime you can'

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I want to arrange an interview, pointing out that I am available at any time convenient to him. I don't know the correct form for saying this. And although he has not asked for my contact information I do want to send it.

Are these sentences correct?

> anytime be convenient for you works for me.
>
> and for offering contact information:
>
> MY skype name is ... and my phone number is ...

Comment: Sorry mari, we don't proofread.

Comment: There are quite a number of grammatical errors in your question, so I shall edit it substantially. You may wish to review my edits and if there is anything you want me to explain I will gladly do so. As for your question I would say *Any convenient time for you will work for me. My contact details are...*

Comment: anytime (_that's_) convenient for you; and _here's my_ contact information. Next time, though, try to isolate what sounds wrong, research online and post a specific problem here if you still need help

Comment: "At a time of your convenience" is a popular phrasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional phrase is *at your convenience*.

> We are so interested that we are willing to come to Waterside, at your convenience, to talk with you and your guardians about doing a movie about your life. — [Source.](https://books.google.nl/books?id=LGmGgOMkUwYC&pg=PA236&dq=%22at+your+convenience%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JCJKVepRhKnsBtaxgZgH&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBjgK)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the correct answer above, if you want to subtly convey that you would prefer to meet sooner rather than later, use *at your earliest convenience*.

Source: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-your-earliest-convenience